# Chart JS + Laravel - How to add 0 to array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, chart.js

**Employees and Projects**

I have a pivot table where my code is grabbing all the projects that an employee is assigned to and the stage they are in.

**Stages**

Waiting
In Progress
Launched

This works and I get the chart to show the data if the employee has projects in each stage. However, when there are not projects in every stage, the array gets messed up and the bar graph shows the data but in the wrong part. For example:

Array that works: [2, 4, 2]
2 Waiting
4 In Progress
2 Launched

Array that doesn't work: [5]
0 Waiting
0 In Progress
5 Launched

In the second case, since the array only has one value, the 5 is shown under Waiting and not launched. How do I add 0's and get the array to show [0, 0, 5]?

Thanks.

```
$projects = Project::join('employee_project', 'projects.id', '=', 'employee_project.project_id')
        ->where('employee_project.employee_id', $id)
        ->groupBy('stage')
        ->select('stage', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->orderByRaw('case 
            when stage = "Waiting" then 1
            when stage = "In Progress" then 2
            when stage = "Launched" then 3
            end')
        ->get();

foreach ($projects as $project) {
        $t[] = $project->total;
    }

    $t = json_encode($t);
```

**Updated Code**

```
foreach ($projects as $project) {
        if ($project->stage == 'Waiting') {
            $t[0] = $project->total;
        } elseif ($project->stage == 'In Progress') {
            $t[1] = $project->total;
        } elseif ($project->stage == 'Launched') {
            $t[2] = $project->total;
        } else {
            $t[] = 0;
        }
    }

    $t = json_encode($t);
```

This updated code gives me an associative array like {"1": 4, "2": 5}.  ChartJS can't use the associative array. It needs an array like [0, 4, 5].
Also, the associative array doesn't include the 0's.

**NEW UPDATE**

```
foreach ($projects as $project) {
        if($project->total > 0) {
            $t[] = $project->total;
        } else {
            $t[] = 0;
        }
    }
```

This doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not pass in an associative array instead?

Comment: as an example if  no project on waiting add '0' as a string.

Comment: Please see my edits in my post that shows how I get the count and then json encode it.

Comment: Just add logic in your `foreach` that places the total in a specific array index based on the `stage` value.  E.g. `if $project->stage == "Waiting" then $t[0] = $project->total else $[0] = 0`, etc...

Comment: Oh yeah duh. Let me give that a try.

Comment: @jordanwillis this works but only for whatever the last project stage is. So it will iterate through all the projects but only put the last project's stage in the array.

Comment: Can you share your updated code?  Did you make sure you initialized your array so that it is length 3 before the loop.  Also, did you remember to use a different index for each of your `stage` values (such that "Waiting" goes into index 0, "In Progress" goes into index 1, etc.)?

Comment: Added another update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. I just had to add an array initializing it. Here is the code:

```
$t = [0,0,0];

    foreach ($projects as $project) {
        if($project->stage === 'Waiting') {
            $t[0] = $project->total;
        } elseif($project->stage === 'In Progress') {
            $t[1] = $project->total;
        } elseif($project->stage === 'Launched') {
            $t[2] = $project->total;
        } else {
            $t[] = $t;
        }
    }

$t = json_encode($t);
```